# Make a MYSQL LEFT JOIN PHP function

Tags: php, mysql, function, left-join

I want to know the idea of making a MYSQL LEFT JOIN function in PHP ..

Like this function fetch_array('tables_names', 'values', 'ON', etc....)
I wanna do it like the function above, to easily fetch left join query..

I hope you understand
and thanks in advance

Comment: Well, what have you tried so far? What issues are you encountering?

Comment: @Christopher my function is too long , its fetches normal SELECT queries, but I dont have the idea for putting left join in it with unlimited left join tables

Comment: PHP has nothing to do with "making" joins in SQL. As far as PHP is concerned, a query which does a join is identical to a query with no joins - it's just a query that returns some rows. There's NO difference in how you retrieve the fields in PHP.

Comment: @Marc the problem is not in retrieving the fields, please read again..

Comment: Use a DB abstraction framework. Other than that, there's nothing else we can help you with.

Comment: At least give me a DB framework name to see how it goes on..

Comment: @phplover What is the real problem? Don't know how to build left join query?

Comment: @xdazz I know how to build it, but need to make it a function to easily use it in the future

Answer (score -1):

I suggest you take the time to learn SQL.

Answer (score -2):

use some framework, zend framework allows for example infinite
$select-> ... ->joinLeft(...)
->joinLeft(...)

Comment: I dont wanna use a framework, I wanna make my own one, but I need a sample code to understand how to do it ...

Comment: try http://framework.zend.com/svn/framework/standard/trunk/library/Zend/Db/Select.php and look at function _join

Comment: how do I do a function like this "$select-> ... ->joinLeft(...) ->joinLeft(...)" ??

Comment: @phplover It is called chain method. `joinLeft()` returns `$this`.